# Scraped data to csv

Tags: python, dataframe, web-scraping, python-requests-html

I have scraped some data from a website - multiple links for multiple pages - and when I run the code it outputs all of the info I am looking for. The problem is I am having difficulty converting it to a data frame and moving it to a CSV file. I think the issue is that I need to convert my dict to a list but I am not sure of this. I am unsure where to go next as I am relatively new to Python.

```
from requests_html import HTMLSession

s = HTMLSession()
def get_product_links(page):
  url = f'https://lakesshoweringspaces.com/catalogue-product-filter/page/{page}'
  links = []
  r = s.get(url)

  products = r.html.find("article.contentwrapper section.collection-wrapper-item")

  for item in products:
    links.append(item.find("a", first=True).attrs['href'].replace('?', ''))
  return links

#page1 = get_product_links(1)
#print(page1)

def parse_product(url):

  r = s.get(url)
  product_type = r.html.find('div.product-sidecontent h3', first=True).text.strip()
  collection = r.html.find('div.product-sidecontent h1', first=True).text.strip()
  description = r.html.find('div.information_grey_section h3.table-title', first=True).text.strip()
  detail = r.html.find('table', first=True)
  tabledata = [[c.text for c in row.find('td')] for row in detail.find('tr')][1:]
  tableheader = [[c.text for c in row.find('th')] for row in detail.find('tr')][0]
  table = [dict(zip(tableheader,t)) for t in tabledata]

  product ={
      'Product Type' : product_type,
      'Collection' : collection,
      'Short Description' : description,
      'Product Data' : table,
  }
  return product

results = []
for x in range(1, 10):
  print('Getting Page ', x)
  urls = get_product_links(x)
  for url in urls:
    print(parse_product(url))
    results.append(parse_product(url))
  print('Total Results: ', len(results))
```

Any help / guidance would be much appreciated.

Comment: Can you edit your question and show a representative sample of your expected output?

Comment: Apologies, I couldn't figure out how to do that. I am trying to create a df that will have the product type, collection & short description but also contain the headers from the table I have scraped as well.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that your list of dict is not consistent in size.

However, the following should do the trick

```
for DICT1 in results:
    all_datax=[]
    for key, value in DICT1.items():
        if isinstance(value, list):
            for idx,(inner_key, inner_value) in enumerate(value[0].items()):
                all_datax.append({f"Product Data {inner_key}_{idx}": inner_value})
        else:
            all_datax.append({key: value})
    all_data.append(dict(pair for d in all_datax for pair in d.items()))
df = pd.DataFrame(all_data)
df.to_excel('lakes.xlsx', index=False)
```

The code iterating through a list of dictionaries (results), and converting the data into a pandas DataFrame which is then saved to an Excel file.

Comment: Hi @mpx - that doesn't seem to have done the trick for me. Many thanks for trying to help me though.

Comment: Based on your post, this is what it seems you desire.

Comment: thanks, but it returns an error for me.                                                              NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-67-bf6153fb0a93> in <module>
      7         else:
      8             all_datax.append({key: value})
----> 9     all_data.append(dict(pair for d in all_datax for pair in d.items()))
     10 df = pd.DataFrame(all_data)
     11 df.to_excel('lakes.xlsx', index=False)

NameError: name 'all_data' is not defined

Comment: could you have a second look for me? where should I sit this in my code? Many thanks for your help.